# Make a C++ macro that acts like a stream

Tags: c++, c, macros, g++

In the absence of help from Google, I wonder if someone could tell me if it is possible to create a C++ (g++) debug macro that acts like, for example, an "improved" std::cout.   Idea is to accept args via << and to append some text so that

```
DBG << "Hello" << world;
```

might produce

```
myfile.cpp 1420 Hello world
```

I know there are logging libraries(?)/macros(?) out there that do this sortof thing.  I'm interested in how it's done, not using some package.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your macro could create a temporary variable which invokes `endl` on destruction. The temporary will stick around until the enclosing expression ends, typically at the `;`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
  ~X() { std::cout << std::endl; }
};

#define DBG (X(), std::cout << __FILE__ << " " << __LINE__ << " ")

int main () {
  std::string world(", world");
  DBG << "Hello" << world;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
#define DBG std::cout << __FILE__ << " " << __LINE__ << " "
```

http://ideone.com/mN5n3

Close enough! Unfortunatelly, you have to declare the variable `world` beforehand.

Comment: One other thought, though, would it be possible to then have the macro append "std::endl"" after the string of <<-ed args.  Yes, I could put it in the front, but what I want is the flush()-ing action more than the CRLF.  All too often std::cout's and std::cerr's never make it to the screnn till something else flushes the output.

Comment: @WesMiller I don't think so no. At least with this syntax it seems impossible.

Comment: Sad.  This all came to mind because I'm a good boy and dont use "using std" which means I get SOOOO tired of typing std::endl and such.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: 90% of which I stole from @LuchianGrigore.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore As you requested.  You still did the heavy lifting, though!  Thanks. Even Rob says so!

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind a debug macro is that it should compile to nothing if you are in release mode. Try this;

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define MESSAGE(x) (std::cout << __FILE__ << " " << __LINE__ << " " << x);
#else
    #define MESSAGE(x) ;
#endif

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MESSAGE("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

When you are in release mode, `MESSAGE(x)` will have no effect, but in debug mode, you will get a message to the command line.

Comment: Well, on second thought, you are still right but sticking to the form of the original question where its DBG << "hello" << world; -- this causes error when _DEBUG is undefined.  The goal was to use the <<'s not DBG( macro_vars ).  I guess I need std::null similar to std::cout but that isn't correct either since the whole mess doesn't compile out in release mode.

Comment: Alas, the MESSAGE(x) form fails if x has any <<'s in it, e.g. MESSAGE( "Hello" << "world";  with 
invalid operands of types ‘const char [6]’ and ‘const char [6]’ to binary ‘operator<<'n

I tried adding some {}s to no avail.

Comment: Yes I did not intend it to be used in that way, really. If you want to use `operator<<`, I guess other answers will suit you better. Your particular error is because "hello" is a string of chars, not an object that implements `operator<<`. It will probably work if you called `MESSAGE("Hello" + "world")`.

Comment: I do like that idea though I wanted to use operator<< with a stringstream because string operator+ lacks overloading to accept noncharacter rhs.  I have not yet moved on to the later C++ standards so I can only wish someone had completed the string class to handle a broader arrays of rhs types and to have, like Qstring, a printf() method.